# Como utilizar o StageWebView

Tags: html, mobile, actionscript-3, webview, adobe-air

Eu preciso implementar um Aplicativo para mostrar textos em HTML já formatados, estes textos estão com imagens.

Eu achei duas opções:
WebView - Mas não consigo utilizar ele como componente, apenas instanciando e jogando na tela.
RichEditableText, este funciona 100% como eu quero, entretanto, o ScrollBar não funciona no mobile, e testes no emulador, funciona apenas quando rolo o botão scroll do mouse

Alguém sabe como resolver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem dois tipos de objetos para exibição de coteúdo HTML, o [HTMLLoader](http://help.adobe.com/pt_BR/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/html/HTMLLoader.html) e o [StageWebView](http://help.adobe.com/pt_BR/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageWebView.html#).

### HTMLLoader

O objeto *HTMLLoader* é o mais prático em se lidar, pois funciona como um **container** para seus elementos HTML. Você pode adicioná-lo como filho de qualquer outro `DisplayObjectContainer` e manipular mais facilmente o conteúdo que está aparecendo, inclusive acessando seus objetos DOMs, assim como o JavaScript faz.

Abaixo há um código simples de como é incorporado o conteúdo dentro de um objeto `HTMLLoader`e exibí-lo no palco:

```
var hl:HTMLLoader = new HTMLLoader(); //Cria o Objeto HTMLLoader
hl.load(new URLRequest("http://www.google.com.br/")); //Carrega o conteúdo HTML, no caso, o site do Google
hl.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completouLoader); //Adiciona o ouvinte COMPLETE

function completouLoader(e:Event):void {
    trace("carregou página");
    hl.width = stage.stageWidth; //Altera o Width e Height do objeto (Por padrão, estes valores possuem 0x0px)
    hl.height = stage.stageHeight;
    addChild(hl); //Adiciona o objeto na tela para exibir a página
}
```

### StageWebView

O *StageWebView* funciona similar ao objeto acima, porém, com funcionalidades limitadas aos eventos do ActionScript e mais simples. Sem falar que este objeto é engessado ao objeto `Stage` da sua aplicação, o que significa que ele sempre estará acima de qualquer objeto de exibição.

Segue um código de exemplo de exibição:

```
var wv:StageWebView = new StageWebView(); //Cria o objeto
wv.viewPort = new Rectangle(0, 0, this.stage.stageWidth, this.stage.stageHeight); //Configura o tamanho e local de exibição do conteúdo
wv.stage = this.stage; //Atrela ao objeto stage da sua aplicação
wv.loadURL("http://www.google.com.br"); //Carrega o conteúdo do site do Google
wv.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, carregou); //Ouvinte de evento Complete
wv.addEventListener(ErrorEvent.ERROR, erro); //Ouvinte de evento Erro

function carregou(e:Event):void {
    trace("Carregou"); //Mais há mais nada a se fazer, após a página carregar toda ação é tomada pelo usuário ou pelos ouvintes disponibilizados pelo objeto "StageWebView"
}

function erro(e:ErrorEvent):void {
    trace("Deu erro.");
    trace(e);
}
```

Estes dois objetos funcionam bem no **Flash Professional**, mas segundo a documentação da Adobe, eles também são compatíveis com **Flex**, que por sua vez possui uma classe chamada [FlexHTMLLoader](http://help.adobe.com/pt_BR/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/FlexHTMLLoader.html), no qual eu desconheço, mas provavelmente deve funcionar similar ao `HTMLLoader`.

Comment: Obrigado biio. Você sabe me dizer se existe um componente para ser chamado pela página? Exemplo: <component:HTMLLoader id="htmlloader">

Eu queria que ele já abrisse em uma telinha que eu controlo sabe?

Comment: Desculpe @RenatoMateusX, sinceramente não tenho conhecimentos em Flex, mas acho que algo parecido com isto: `<mx:HTML id="HTMLLoader"/>`. Rsrs